# Solving matrix equations over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

If $AX = B$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are known, and $A$ is not a square matrix. It is desired to solve for the value of the matrix $X$. The elements of the matrix are 0/1, i.e., they are over a binary field $\mathbb F_2$.

I only know how equations on the real number field should be solved. I hope I can get help from you, thanks a lot!

Comment: The **algorithm** for solving a linear system of equations is the same for every field (elementary row operations FTW). If anything the field $\Bbb{F}_2$ is easier because you never need to perform any divisions. Exactly which steps are you having trouble with? Show some work on an example case, and then we can give specific help!

Comment: If $A$ is square and invertible, then $X=A^{-1}B$. For nonsquare matrices, in your case, you could utilise the left inverse; therefore, you get $X=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$. Notice $A^TA$ is invertible when $A$ has full column rank.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_k$ and $b_k$ be the $k$-th column of $X$ and $B$ respectively. Then $Ax_k=b_k$. This linear system can be solved with Gaussian elimination over every field.